# gem install ruby-debug19 fails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-debug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Debugging in ruby 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083451/debugging-in-ruby-1-9)

I am unable to install ruby-debug19.
I tried to follow http://isitruby19.com/linecache19 BUT it didnot help me
I also followed the steps in [Installing Gems without rvm, as root, with explicit version of ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700828/installing-gems-without-rvm-as-root-with-explicit-version-of-ruby/7781550#7781550)
that also didnt help

======================================

```
> root@vm:/# ruby -v ruby 
> 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
```

======================================

```
> root@vm:/# gem -v
> 1.8.10
```

======================================

```
> root@vm:~/# uname -a 
> Linux vm 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:50:42 UTC 2011 i686 i686 386 GNU/Linux
```

======================================

> `root@vm:~# sudo gem install ruby-debug19`

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...


    ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug19:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    checking for vm_core.h... no
    checking for vm_core.h... no
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
            --with-opt-dir
            --without-opt-dir
            --with-opt-include
            --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
            --with-opt-lib
            --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
            --with-make-prog
            --without-make-prog
            --srcdir=.
            --curdir
            --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
            --with-ruby-dir
            --without-ruby-dir
            --with-ruby-include
            --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
            --with-ruby-lib
            --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize': Connection timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `open'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `block in connect'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `connect'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1168:in `request'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:239:in `block in read'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:286:in `connect'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:234:in `read'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:128:in `download'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:55:in `block in create_makefile_with_core'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:320:in `open'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:51:in `create_makefile_with_core'
            from extconf.rb:19:in `<main>'
    Requesting http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p290.tar.gz

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache19-0.5.12 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out
```

[Installing ruby-debug19 locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169169/installing-ruby-debug19-locally)
I got the answer to the question from above link which worked
basically put all *.h *.c *.inc files into below folder

```
ruby -rmkmf -e 'puts Config::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"] + "/" + "ruby-" + RUBY_VERSION.to_s + "-p" + RUBY_PATCHLEVEL.to_s'
```

But i am not happy with this soultion. If i ask a customer to install ruby i can hardly expect to sell this particular solution to the problem.

So is there a way to avoid this copying?

Can someone please help me.
Thanks
Su

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what OS you are running, but I had a similar problem a while back with my OSX Lion install. The error was for a different gem, but the error was the same.

It turned out to be some sort of XCode version conflict. [See my solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10458609/404993)

If that doesn't help, then check out the `mkmf.log` file. It might contain clues to the answers you are looking for.

Comment: root@vm:~/# uname -a
Linux vm 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:50:42 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
it is ubuntu oneric linux box

Comment: Not sure on Ubuntu. Try going to `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems` and doing `find . | grep mkmf.log`